# WSO2 GovernanceServer and Google Protocol buffers

Tags: wso2, soa

We are starting to look at WSO2 Governance Registry software for our SOA Governance(so I'm just beginning to dig into this product).  I see that you can auto-build governance data by pointing to a WSDL if you use web services.
Does anyone know if there is any way to do this auto-build by pointing to a Google Protocol Buffer .proto file?

This has our Message formats, and our Service details, so it would be very nice to be able to do that.
IF there isn't anything like that, COULD something be developed to do that (and if so, and pointers to the documentation I would need would be great!).

We are NOT using WebServices, so no WSDL's.....
Thanks!

Comment: This capability of pointing to a proto file and crating a service is not possible with WSO2 Governance Registry now.

Answer (score 0):

This capability of pointing to a proto file and crating a service is not possible with WSO2 Governance Registry now.

However it is possible to add this as a new feature, and should be a simple implementation. AFAIK, this will be as simple as creating a handler to deal with proto file as a media type, and do the same stuff we do for a WSDL in that handler, and create a service out of that.

Having a WSDL is not a must to create a service. We can represent non-SOAP services too, in WSO2 Governance Registry.

Comment: I do realize we could update the Service items manually, but it would be great to be able to read the .proto file and have it built/updated automatically.  Is there any documentation (or can I get the code for the WSDL handler???)

Comment: In addition, I tried the WSDL extraction, but I don't see that it pulled out any metadata/information concerning the actual methods for the Web Service call -- where (is??) that data stored and how do I view it?